# How to adjust the content to the main window in pyqt5, when it's geometry is fixed or being changed?

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5, widget

I am creating a custom control and want to create a row of buttons. For the beginning I started with two buttons, the code looks like that:

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
  
        self.setWindowTitle("Python ")
  
        self.setGeometry(500, 600, 200, 200)

        self.UiComponents()
  
        self.show()

    def UiComponents(self):
      
            button1 = QPushButton( "", self)
            button2 = QPushButton( "", self)
            button1.setGeometry(10, 150, 100, 100)
            button2.setGeometry(150, 150, 100, 100)
```

The problem is that the buttons don't fit into the window (because of the geometry setting I guess). My purpose is when running the code that the main window shows for example 20 buttons in a row without being cut off (meaning regardless of the number of buttons).

How do I get the buttons or window to the correct size or how can I adjust the buttons to the main window or the main window to the content?

How do I get a row of circular buttons that meet the same requirements?

```
def Function(self):
xpos = 10

for i in range(5):

    button = QPushButton("".format(i+1), self)
    button.setGeometry(xpos, 150, 50, 50 )
    xpos = xpos + 50
    button.setStyleSheet("border : 1px solid black;background-color : green; border-radius : 25px")
    button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=i+1: self.function(i))     
    button.clicked.connect(lambda ch, i=button : self.color(i))
```

Comment: You need to use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html). Note that you cannot set a layout on a QMainWindow: you need to set a *central widget* (a basic QWidget instance will suffice) and set the layout for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a layout. A simple implementation of one might be

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        mainWidget = QWidget()
        mainLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setCentralWidget(mainWidget)
        mainWidget.setLayout(mainLayout)
```

and then pack your buttons in like

```
        button1 = QPushButton("")
        button2 = QPushButton("")
        button3 = QPushButton("")
        mainLayout.addWidget(button)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button2)
        mainLayout.addWidget(button3)
```

In this example, they would appear in order in a horizontal column, but you there are [several layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/overviews/layout.html).

Comment: It would be useful to clarify why one cannot do `self.setLayout()` on a QMainWindow and must use `setCentralWidget()`.

Comment: @musicamante If I knew maybe haha, comment it and I'll edit it in.

Comment: Well, a basic search about "QMainWindow setLayout" provides enough results to get started with.

Comment: You already answered and this answer *is* effective; I clearly said that "it would be useful" to add that information, not that I didn't agree, nor that your answer wasn't valid. Creating a new answer with the same concept would be pointless and unnecessary. Improving *your* answer would clearly be an improvement, instead: for the OP, for yourself, and the answer itself. But, hey, it's a free world, if you don't want to dig into it, that's fine: it's you that said "If I knew". Anybody can now read these comments and know how to improve their knowledge. If you don't want to, that's your choice.

Comment: Well, as explained in the [tour], SO is *not* a forum. I already provided enough basis for what you should have provided; SO rules require a minimal research effort, and while that effort is mostly required for questions, answers are not excluded from that: we don't have to tell you what to write, unless you ask for clarifications you didn't find on your own. That's how we try to keep our quality as high as possible: we suggest resources, directly or not. And this is where I'll stop commenting on this matter, because (as you should already know) comments should only *improve* contents.

Comment: thx for the help. Is it also possible to use the proposed approach for buttons looking like circles?

Comment: @user19340419 This approach can be used for tiling any widget in any way, go nuts! I like to manage my styles in a top level applied multi-line string that I format like a CSS file